# Get reference to an Outook message duplicate

Tags: outlook, applescript

This code will duplicate a Microsoft Outlook `message` to the `drafts` folder:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

  ...

  -- find the template give an ID
  set theTemplate to message id theID

  -- duplicate the message  
  duplicate theTemplate to drafts

  ...

end tell
```

I need a reference to the duplicate for additional processing.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work:

```
...

-- this will create a duplicate
set theDuplicate to (duplicate theTemplate to drafts)

-- produces an error that reads "The variable theDuplicate is not defined."
display dialog (subject of theDuplicate) & " [" & (id of theDuplicate) & "]"
```

How do I get a reference to the message that was just duplicated?  Its ID would be a satisfactory alternative.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way but...

```
--For Testing
set theID to 39110

tell application "Microsoft Outlook"    
    set oldIds to my getDraftIds()

    -- find the template give an ID
    set theTemplate to message id theID

    --duplicate the message  
    duplicate theTemplate to drafts

    set newIds to my getDraftIds()
    set duplicatedMessage to message id (my findNewID(oldIds, newIds))
end tell


on getDraftIds()
    set messageIDs to {}
    tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
        set draftFolders to (every folder whose name = "Drafts")
        repeat with dFolder in draftFolders
            set messageIDs to messageIDs & id of dFolder's messages
        end repeat
    end tell
end getDraftIds

on findNewID(oldList, newList)
    repeat with mID in newList
        if mID is not in oldList then return mID
    end repeat
end findNewID
```

Comment: +1  I was considering a similar approach.  I don't suppose there is a way to do a `NOT IN` query.

Comment: Another thought: the API supports an optional `[with properties record]' statement.  Perhaps I could add a dummy property (without losing all of the original properties), then get the message with the dummy property.  Thoughts?

Comment: I like the idea, although I don't see a message property that would be a good placeholder for a dummy value.

Comment: How about setting a temporary category on the message to be duplicated?  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the duplicate method is pretty limited in this regard.  I tried the more generic copy method too - the message is copied, but again no ID is returned.

Here's another possible way to do this with no repeat loops:

- Create a new, temporary category
- Mark the original message with the new category
- Duplicate - the duplicate message will also be marked with the category
- search for messages marked with the temporary category - you should only get two - the original and the duplicate
- Delete the temporary category

Here is the code (rather unfinished):

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    try
        set tempCategory to category "Temporary Category"
    on error number -1728
        set tempCategory to (make new category with properties {name:"Temporary Category"})
    end try

    set messageList to selected objects
    set origMsg to item 1 of messageList
    display dialog "Original Message ID: " & id of origMsg

    set msgCat to category of origMsg
    set end of msgCat to tempCategory
    set category of origMsg to msgCat

    duplicate origMsg to drafts
    delay 1 -- sigh, it seems to take a bit of time before the category markings are reflected in the spotlight DB

    --set msgList to messages whose category contains tempCategory
    set currentIdentityFolder to quoted form of POSIX path of (current identity folder as string)
    set tempCatMsgs to words of (do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & currentIdentityFolder & " 'com_microsoft_outlook_categories == " & id of tempCategory & "' | xargs -I % mdls -name com_microsoft_outlook_recordID '%' | cut -d'=' -f2 | sort -u | paste -s -")

    if item 1 of tempCatMsgs is (id of origMsg) as text then
        set dupMsgId to item 2 of tempCatMsgs
    else
        set dupMsgId to item 1 of tempCatMsgs
    end if

    delete tempCategory

    display dialog "Original Message ID: " & id of origMsg & return & "Duplicate Message ID: " & dupMsgId
end tell
```

I thought it would be easier to find messages with a given category using the OL dictionary, but instead had to resort a spotlight search.  I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

Also adding a category to a message was harder than I though - again I'm sure this can be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- create a temporary folder to hold duplicates
on createFolder(theName)

  tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theFolder to make new mail folder with properties {name:theName}
  end tell

end createFolder

-- find folder by name
on findFolder(theName)

  tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    set theFolder to make new mail folder with properties {name:theName}
  end tell

end findFolder

-- duplicate the message and get a reference
on duplicateIt(theID)

  set theDestination to findFolder("foo bar")

  tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    --find the template
    set theTemplate to message id theID

    -- duplicate it to the temporary location
    (duplicate theTemplate to theDestination)

    -- get the first item in the folder
    set theDuplicate to item 1 of theDestination

    -- do something with it
    ...

  end tell

end duplicateIt
```